# javascript ui to maven interface over http

Tags: javascript, maven

Is there a javascript read only tool for rendering information in maven repositories?  Currently, we use archiva to do this, but archiva requires alot of stuff under the hood - a database, user permissions, etc... and all we really need is the snazzy "click on a jar" download ui and ability to browse versions.

Since maven repos are, after all , just folders in an http published directory, a JS interface should (theoretically) allow one to easily navigate and download from a simple s3:// or other swift:// repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spun up a simple javascript interface to my maven repository and it works.

The way it works : Use JQuery to get the releases from maven-metadata.xml, and then generate links to jar files from that.  Its not perfect, but its solves my needs, is dynamic, and is also completely serverless.

For the most part, it can be copy/pasted and used for any maven repo, i think...

http://jayunit100.blogspot.com/2014/01/ajax-maven-s3-lightweight-maven.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but a proper repository manager is in fact the way to go. Which one depends on many factors, not in the least personal preference. And I've discarded Archiva in the past for being utterly incomprehensible. Nexus and Artifactory have always been very intuitive and user friendly. If you don't like (big) databases underneath, Artifactory may not be for you, since it stores everything in JCR database (although the authors stand behind their design choice). Nexus is more file-system friendly, and we ended up using it.

Bite the bullet on a repository manager. It's definitely worth it. Once Maven becomes more commonplace in  your organization, you'll want to use other things it has to offer.

Comment: We are working with nexus and it's easy and powerful, try it.

Comment: Archiva Release 1.3.6 is actually pretty nice im not sure what your issues were?  For us - we only have one jar and not alot of public servers so we figure, why bother manage a server just for a UI to static jars

Comment: As I said, it was personal preference. Use Archiva if that suits you. The real point was to use a proper repository manager instead of "messing around".